# Couchdb - query.keys with empty dictionary

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I've written a map function that has

```
emit([doc.university,doc.degree,doc.studentName],1)
```

Now, I'd like to query the exact rows (not a key range) as following

```
query.keys = [[university1,degree1,{}],[university2,degree2,{}]]
```

Is this possible with CouchDB [querying option](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)- Keys? I'm fetching all the students (sorted based on their name) that belong to specific degrees and universities.

P.S I'm an iOS dev working with Couchbase-lite and not an expert on CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible since there is no wildcards in couchDB, but you could easily achieve the same result by creating a new view that is the same as your current one but emits:

```
emit([doc.university,doc.degree],doc.studentName)
```

and use the query:

```
query.keys = [[university1,degree1],[university2,degree2]]
```

Comment: But that emit will not sort rows based on studentName :(

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But you could solve that by sorting the result in your application, or by doing two requests to your view and append them in your application:
`?startkey=[university1,degree1]&endkey=[university1,degree1,"\ufff0"]`
`?startkey=[university2,degree2]&endkey=[university2,degree2,"\ufff0"]`

Comment: I've to paginate the results. So, when the limit is applied I can't sort in memory, nor can I make two requests.

Comment: Then you might have to do it in a list function, this will be rather slow since it's not precalculated but you can send parameters to it.